# How to link Google Drive Push Notification Response to a changed file

Tags: c#, .net, push-notification, google-drive-api

I am trying out google drive api and creating an application with it.

My goal is to upload a file to drive, and download the latest version from drive. When I open the file in drive, I have got the channel created.

I am creating watch on all changes and not just file. In my understanding, this means that it will inform me of all the changes on all files.

Now, if I change the file, I get the notification POST response from drive. In the documentation, i see that ResourceId has no meaning to us.

So how should I map the notification response to a file in order to download the changed file from drive using get file.

Please guide.

Comment: What do you mean that you dont need the ResourceId. That's the ID of the file you're trying to watch. Have you implemented any codes yet?

Comment: Hi @noogui, ResourceId is not the fileId. I have edited different files but resourceId is always same and it doesn't matches with any file I have changed. I have tested it. Also, the statement that I made about ResourceId not needed is from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3g_oT03nmQ from google docs about PushNotifications.

Answer (score 1):

> To use push notifications, you need to do three things:
>
> Register the domain of your receiving URL.
>
> For example, if you plan to use mydomain.com/notifications as
>   your receiving URL, you need to register mydomain.com. Set up
>   your receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.

This is an HTTPS server that handles the API notification messages that are triggered when a resource changes.

Set up a notification channel for each resource endpoint you want to watch.

A channel specifies routing information for notification messages. As part of the channel setup, you identify the specific URL where you want to receive notifications. Whenever a channel's resource changes, the Drive API sends a notification message as a POST request to that URL.

You'll be writing [watch requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#making-watch-requests) for you to see changes to a particular resource. Check this [Drive Push guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @noogui, I was able to implement it based on creating channel for each resource. I figured out that resource id is the folder id in which file is being stored in google drive. One thing I wanted to confirm is that these channels have expiration time, that they don't stay after a couple of hours and no notifications are sent after that. One solution is to create another channel after it expires. Is there any other solution? And what is the expiration time of the channel? Is it fixed?